# ERB end tag for label_tag after a block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I need an ERB that will generate HTML label with end tag after a block like this:

```
<label for="pic1" class="pic_s"><div>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Download_link.png" >
</div></label>
```

I tried using this ERB code:

```
<%= radio_button_tag('pic', nil, :class => idx) do %>
<div><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Download_link.png"></div>
<% end %>
```

but it gives me syntax error. Also tried:

```
<%= label_tag 'pic', nil, :class => idx, raw("#{image_tag image}") %>
```

But still giving syntax error. I'm using rails 2.3.17 and according to https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/label_tag only version >=3.0.0 takes a block. Is there another way to accomplish this without updating rails? It seems such a small problem that does not justify and an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `content_tag`?

```ruby
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb
class ApplicationHelper
  def download_label
    content_tag :label, { :for => 'pic1', :class => 'pic_s' } do
      content_tag :div do
        image_tag('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Download_link.png')
      end
    end
  end
end

# erb file
<%= download_label %>
```

Comment: Using that code it gives syntax error on apache's error.log and the application won't load at all. Here is the error.log: Message from application: ..../app/helpers/application_helper.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected ':'
    content_tag :label, { for: 'pic1', class: 'pic_s' } do
                              ^
So I removed the comma but it still give another error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting kEND
    content_tag :label { for: 'pic1', class: 'pic_s' } do

Comment: Hmm.. I don't think that there is a problem with comma. Probably there is old hash syntax with hashrocket. I've edited my answer, can you try it now?